# Temporarily remove URL from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've created a Twitter bot that copies the tweet of a certain user and then uwu-fies them, meaning it just changes some characters to make them funny, Elon becomes Ewon for example. Now of course it's very debatable how funny this actually is but I think that's besides the point for now.

If I got a tweet with a URL, of course the URL can't be uwu-fied since it would become invalid. The way I've sold this right now is, search for the URL using a regex, replace it with a `performance.now()` (I used to use a UUID v4 but that also contains characters that would get uwu-fied) and save an object with the URL and `performance.now()` that was used.

Then when the uwu-fication is done I can reconstruct is using the saved object, this does work but it feels like a bodged solution. The only other solution I could think of is generating a UUID that only contains characters that won't get uwu-fied?

**EDIT:**

Based of the current marked answer I've solved the problem by transforming my code into this:

```
// Split the sentence into words
const words = sentence.split(` `);
const pattern = new RegExp(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/g);

// If the word is a URL just attach it to the new string without uwufying
let uwufied = ``;
words.forEach(word => uwufied += ` ${pattern.test(word) ? word : uwufyWord(word)}`);
```

Comment: Can't you add special markers around url and modify your uwu-fier to ignore them like [https://twitter.com/user/status/123] ?

Comment: The easiest is to use `.replace(/(https?:\/\/\S*)|(?:(?!https?:\/\/\S)[^])+/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $1 : uwufy($0); })`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you maybe elebate on your answer? I don't quite understand it

Comment: @Viney the links appears to be dead but I do get the idea :)

Comment: All URLs are skipped and the text that is not a URL is passed to `uwufy` method and replaced in the target text string. The regex is not the best, it can be improved, it is just a showcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the tweet into an array `.split(" ")`, and then run over that array with a foreach loop. You can handle the tweet word by word then. At the start of your handle process you would check that the "word" is **not** an url. Then handle your replacements.

```js
let tweet = "Hello World. What's up?"
let arr = tweet.split(" ")
let output = ""

for (word of arr) {
  // Check that it's not an URL here
  // Replace here
  output += word + " "
}

// Use output here
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Ah ofcourse! Thank you very much for the input, I've also expanded my question to include the code I used to solve the problem based on your answer :)